# Test an angular service using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a problem with testing a simple service in angularJS, and after reading a dozen tutorials and articles I don't get what's wrong with my code, maybe you could help me a bit.

My service is purposingly simple so I don't have to worry about it's code. It's a getter/setter service with the following code :

```
app.service("GetterSetterService", function() {

  item = "";

  return {
    get: function() {
      return item;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      item = value;
    }
  }
});
```

when "app" has been defined as follow :

```
var app = angular.module('myTestApplication', ["ngMock"]);
```

My testing code with Jasmine is the following :

```
"use strict";

describe("GetterSetterService", function() {

  var service;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_GetterSetterService_) {
    service = _GetterSetterService_;
  }));

  it("correctly defines the service", function() {
    expect(service).not.toBeUndefined();
    expect(service).not.toBeNull()
  });

  it("has a default value if no value has been set", function() {
    expect(service.get()).toBe("");
  });

  it("correctly sets a value", function() {
    service.set("newValue");
    expect(service.get()).toBe("newValue");
  });
});
```

But if I put traces, it never passes in the "inject" callback, thus doesn't inject the service, and doesn't work properly. Does anyone has a clue about what's wrong ? I don't get it and I'm getting desperate.

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

Is this the complete test? If so then you're missing the loading of the application definiton. E.g.

```
beforeEach(module('myTestApplication'));
```

Also you don't need to inject `ngMocks` into the actual application - this is only concerned with mocking out tests so you would only have it in the `karma.conf.js` file.

So based on the above I think your understanding is alittle off when it comes to testing. You need to:

1. Ensure the necessary files are included in the karma.conf.js file
2. Load the module using `beforeEach` syntax as described above
3. Inject what you're testing - which you are doing correctly.
4. Define and run your tests